# How to Watch Window Variables from Within AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a group of window variables that I want to bind to a scope variable in AngularJS.

Here's my code so far but it doesn't work:

```
        .directive('watchGlobals', function() {
            return {
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                        var watchGlobals = attrs.watchGlobals.split(',');
                        for (var i = 0; i < watchGlobals.length; i++) {
                            scope[watchGlobals[i]] = window[watchGlobals[i]];
                        }
                }
            }
        });
```

What's the optimal way to do this? I'm trying to avoid having to use setInterval. I'd like to have the scopes updated whenever the window variable is updated. Is there a way I can watch window variables from within AngularJS like this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I'm trying to watch variables in one application and use them in another.

Comment: From raw JavaScript to AngularJS

Comment: Is your other application an angular app?

Comment: It's not an AngularJS app - it's raw JavaScript

Comment: jQuery would be ideal but I already wrote the app in AngularJS

Comment: you could use something like https://github.com/rndme/watcher, but it's generally better to push notifications than it is to observe.

Comment: how do I push notifications?

Comment: I agree with @dandavis. Use a simple js pubsub, that you can subscribe to inside a service in angular. The other app should publish via the pubsub, which will invoke the call in the service. The service will update the angular app.

Comment: @user2476265: there is no single "way" to do it, it's just a low-level idea. but, honing in, everytime you set a global in the old script, you would call a controller method from the same place in code. yes, you have to modify the old script to do this, whereas observing can get it done (slightly less efficiently) without touching the existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple js pubsub (for example [PubSubJs](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS)), that you can subscribe to inside a service in angular. The other app should publish via the pubsub, which will invoke the call in the service. The service will update the angular app.

```
angular.factory('connectService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    var token = PubSub.subscribe( 'TOPIC_NAME', function(msg, data) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('TOPIC_NAME', { msg: msg, data: data });
        });
    });

}]);
```

From the other app you can now publish the data:

```
PubSub.publish( 'MY TOPIC', 'hello world!' );
```

Now whenever you want to want to get the data in angular use:

```
$scope.$on('TOPIC_NAME', function(data) {
    console.log(data.msg, data.data); // do whatever you want to do with the data
});
```

Comment: why not just call the controller from the other code instead of an EE middleman?

Comment: This is an external data, and I usually wrap external sources in a service, which is a singleton and won't be destroyed during the app lifetime.. You can do it in a controller if it suits your taste.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments says there are many ways this can be done, and pushing data is probably better than listening for it.

You can use a simple hook into angular to simply call a `$digest` on your existing directive's scope. Then instead of watching the variable value as you are currently, use a function to return the current value of the window property. This way you don't lose the watch if the value is a simple type (string, number) or is replaced:

```js
/*** angular code ***/

angular.module('myApp', [])

    .controller('ctrl', function() {})

    // inject the standard angular $window service (really just the window object)
    .directive('watchGlobals', function($window) {
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                // add a method to the raw DOM element that JS can call to update the scope
                element[0].externalUpdate = function() {
                    scope.$digest();
                };

                var watchGlobals = attrs.watchGlobals.split(',');
                // loop as before, but use an IIFE to isolate the variable name
                for (var i = 0; i < watchGlobals.length; i++) {
                    (function(variable) {
                        scope.$watch(function() { return $window[variable]; }, // use a function
                                     function(newVal) { scope[variable] = newVal; }); // update scope
                    })(watchGlobals[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });

/*** JS code ***/

// global function to update angular scope
function updateAngular() {
    // find the directive element and call it's externalUpdate() function
    // this is the only "bit in the middle" of the 2 apps
    document.getElementById('angular-hook').externalUpdate();

    // alternative option, but breaks with $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false)
    //angular.element(document.getElementById('angular-hook')).scope().$digest();
}

function setValueX() {
    window.xVal = document.getElementById('valX').value;
    updateAngular();
}

function setValueY() {
    window.yVal = document.getElementById('valY').value;
    updateAngular();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h2>Angular</h2>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <div id="angular-hook" watch-globals="xVal,yVal"></div>
        <p>x: {{xVal}}</p>
        <p>y: {{yVal}}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<h2>JS</h2>
<p>X: <input type="text" id="valX" /> <button onclick="setValueX()">Set</button></p>
<p>Y: <input type="text" id="valY" /> <button onclick="setValueY()">Set</button></p>
```

**UPDATE:** Changed the `scope().$digest()` call to a DOM element function to get around turning off debugInfo.

Comment: There is a problem with this method if you use `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);` - the scope won't be available from outside angular using `angular.element(document.getElementById('angular-hook')).scope()`.